# Dropwizard and hibernate project has startup issue with classloader error

Tags: hibernate, rest, h2, dropwizard, connection-pool

I have attempted working with SQLite and h2 databases, with the sqlite-jdbc-3.20.1.jar /h2-1.4.195.jar in the classpath.

I have the h2 driver jar in my pom.xml, didn't seem to make a difference at runtime.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.195</version>
</dependency>
```

I copied the jars to target directory in the hopes that "java -cp target/*" might get these jars right into the class path. All to no avail. I am getting this error that's driving me crazy, it won't tell me what class it didn't find

```
    Causing: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class:
```

from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2;ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2

`         ... 24 more
...
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   
>             at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  
>             at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)  
>         at > >org.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38)
> ```

I have printed the maven tree and used verbose:class option and do find  driver class loaded. I have dropwizard-hibernate package in my maven dependencies.
OK, any way to coerce this thing to tell me which class it is not able to find?!

Addendum:

My Config.yml

```
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    com.srini.testdw: DEBUG
database:
  driverClass: org.h2.Driver
  user: "sa"
  password: ""
  url: jdbc:h2:./testdb
  properties:
    charSet: UTF-8
    maxWaitForConnection: 1s
    validationQuery: "/* MyService Health Check */ SELECT 1"
    minSize: 8
    maxSize: 32
    checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
    evictionInterval: 10s
    minIdleTime: 1 minute
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate.show_sql: true
    hibernate.generate_statistics: false
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: validate

server:
  minThreads: 2
  maxQueuedRequests: 3
  type: simple
```

Comment: Could you post the configuration of your tomcat connection pool? The root cause is most likely that the pool is not able to load the configured JDBC driver. https://apache.googlesource.com/tomcat/+/d000040c312f0b303293ad7ac8a67e88ff1850cb/java/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PooledConnection.java#133

Comment: @Andreas, I am using the built in jetty server, not sure at all. There is nothing specific in the config.yml I have used for pool configuration.

Comment: in your config is a section `database:` this section has a property `driverClass : org.postgresql.Driver`. The value you have set there is most likely wrong.
You are using the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool, there is no relation between the servlet container (Jetty, Tomcat, Undertow) and your database connection pool (Tomcat, Hikari, C3PO) despite being programmed by the Tomcat team and often used with a Tomcat servlet container.

Comment: database:  
  driverClass: org.h2.Driver  
  user: "sa"  
  password: ""  
  url: jdbc:h2:./testdb  
  properties:  
    charSet: UTF-8  
    maxWaitForConnection: 1s  
    validationQuery: "/* MyService Health Check */ SELECT 1"  
    minSize: 8  
    maxSize: 32  
    checkConnectionWhileIdle: false  
    evictionInterval: 10s  
    minIdleTime: 1 minute    
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect     
    hibernate.show_sql: true  
    hibernate.generate_statistics: false

Comment: Sorry, couldn't seem to be able to format the config.yml I posted above

Comment: Looks like I resolved the problem accidentally, without having to change anything much. The server configuration in my config.yml reads "simple", looks  like getting rid of that resolved my issue. Thank you @Andreas for your inputs